# Why is the image of the map $Im\left(I\otimes M\hookrightarrow M\right)=IM$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

> Let $R$ be a ring $M\in Mod_R$ an $R$-module and $I\subset R$ be an ideal. I consider the obvious inclusion map $I\hookrightarrow R$ and apply the functor $-\otimes M$. Then I see that this gives me $I\otimes M\hookrightarrow M$.

I thought that $i\otimes m\mapsto m$. But then the image would only be $M$. In the lecture our prof said that the image is $IM$ and I somehow do not se why. Could maybe someone explain this to me?

**Update**
Is it correct that we have the following universal property?
[image]

Comment: The map $I\otimes M\hookrightarrow M$ is given by $i\otimes m\mapsto i \cdot m$.

Comment: @OlivierRoche aha okey so here we use like the action on the $R$-module i.e. we restrict the action $R\times M\rightarrow M$ to $I\times M\rightarrow M$?

Comment: Correct. Check that this is a an $R$-bilinear map so it naturally induces a map from $R \otimes M \to M$ ( and from $I \otimes M \to M$ by restriction as you have mentioned.)

Comment: @Arkady I updated my question, so is it correct that your point in your comment comes from this universal property I draw above? (where I consider $R$ as an $R$-module over itself)

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Arkady perfect thanks! Can I ask you if you maybe could take a look at my other question I posted on MSE?